# Adding to a starting value in a list each time for loop runs?

Tags: python, for-loop, addition

I'm trying to add value `z` to starting value `x` each time the following for loop runs. The output I'm expecting is `1000,1021,1042,1063...` or `x, x+z, x+z+z, x+z+z+z...`

When I run the following, I only get `1000,1021` as the output.

Why am I only getting a list of two values when the range is 0-1000? I'm obviously very new to python, so I'm sure the answer is something simple that I haven't come across yet.

Thanks for your time!

`

```
x = [1000]
y = []
z = 21
for i in range(0,1000):
    y = np.append(x,sum(x,z))
print(y)
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your query is independent of the loop variable `i`, the loop is running for 1000 times but it does not do anything.

Before the loop exits, it adds two elements to `y` i.e. `x` and `sum(x,z)`, which are `1000` and `1021`, hence you get the output `[1000 1021]`

You can try the below code to increment every time by z using [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function

```
for i in range(1000, 1100, z):
    y.append(i)
print(y)
#Output: 1000, 1021, 1042, 1063, 1084
```